# Find the average of a number on a per minute basis

Tags: r, datetime, xts

I've got a data frame with the following:

```
        Id     final_date_time Speed
2022484408 2016-04-12 07:21:00    97
2022484405 2016-04-12 07:21:05   102
2022484402 2016-04-12 07:21:10   105
2022484407 2016-04-12 07:21:20   103
2022484408 2016-04-12 07:21:25   101
2022484408 2016-04-12 07:22:05    95
2022484410 2016-04-12 07:22:10    91
2022484408 2016-04-12 07:22:15    93
2022484421 2016-04-12 07:22:20    94
2022484408 2016-04-12 07:22:25    93
2022484421 2016-04-12 07:22:35    92
2022484421 2016-04-12 07:22:40    89
2022484447 2016-04-12 07:22:50    83
2022484488 2016-04-12 07:22:55    61
2022484411 2016-04-12 07:23:00    60
```

The class of "final_date_time" is POSIXct.
How can I find the average of "Speed" on a per minute basis?

Here is the dput info:

```
structure(list(Id = c(2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408, 
2022484408, 2022484408), new_final_date = structure(c(1460438460, 
1460438465, 1460438470, 1460438480, 1460438485, 1460438525), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Value = c(97L, 102L, 105L, 103L, 101L, 
95L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried a solution that worked on a previous similar problem, (changed the labels), but I couldn't get it to work:

```
library(xts)
x <- as.xts(dd[,date := as.POSIXct(date)])
period.apply(x, endpoints(x, "minutes", 15), mean)
```

Comment: Provide reproducible data, `dput(head(dd))`

Comment: structure(list(Id = c(2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408, 
2022484408, 2022484408), new_final_date = structure(c(1460438460, 
1460438465, 1460438470, 1460438480, 1460438485, 1460438525), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Value = c(97L, 102L, 105L, 103L, 101L, 
95L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(x)

x[, .(avg = mean(Speed)), .(Id, interval = cut(final_date_time, breaks = "1 min"))]

#             Id            interval     avg
# 1:  2022484408 2016-04-12 07:21:00  99.000
# 2:  2022484405 2016-04-12 07:21:00 102.000
# 3:  2022484402 2016-04-12 07:21:00 105.000
# 4:  2022484407 2016-04-12 07:21:00 103.000
# 5:  2022484408 2016-04-12 07:22:00  93.667
# 6:  2022484410 2016-04-12 07:22:00  91.000
# 7:  2022484421 2016-04-12 07:22:00  91.667
# 8:  2022484447 2016-04-12 07:22:00  83.000
# 9:  2022484488 2016-04-12 07:22:00  61.000
# 10: 2022484411 2016-04-12 07:23:00  60.000
```

***I assumed you want to group on Id as well, if not, remove `Id`**

`x[, .(avg = mean(Speed)), .(interval = cut(final_date_time, breaks = "1 min"))]`

Answer (score 2):

This becomes very easy if you switch to `data.table`.  To do so, we first correct your question by making the data readable. I use `data.table` for that too, and added commas to your data which was actually not readable: four actual columns with three columns names:

```
> D <- fread(text="Id,    final_date_time, Speed
+ 2022484408, 2016-04-12 07:21:00,    97
+ 2022484405, 2016-04-12 07:21:05,   102
+ 2022484402, 2016-04-12 07:21:10,   105
+ 2022484407, 2016-04-12 07:21:20,   103
+ 2022484408, 2016-04-12 07:21:25,   101
+ 2022484408, 2016-04-12 07:22:05,    95
+ 2022484410, 2016-04-12 07:22:10,    91
+ 2022484408, 2016-04-12 07:22:15,    93
+ 2022484421, 2016-04-12 07:22:20,    94
+ 2022484408, 2016-04-12 07:22:25,    93
+ 2022484421, 2016-04-12 07:22:35,    92
+ 2022484421, 2016-04-12 07:22:40,    89
+ 2022484447, 2016-04-12 07:22:50,    83
+ 2022484488, 2016-04-12 07:22:55,    61
+ 2022484411, 2016-04-12 07:23:00,    60")
> D
            Id     final_date_time Speed
         <int>              <POSc> <int>
 1: 2022484408 2016-04-12 07:21:00    97
 2: 2022484405 2016-04-12 07:21:05   102
 3: 2022484402 2016-04-12 07:21:10   105
 4: 2022484407 2016-04-12 07:21:20   103
 5: 2022484408 2016-04-12 07:21:25   101
 6: 2022484408 2016-04-12 07:22:05    95
 7: 2022484410 2016-04-12 07:22:10    91
 8: 2022484408 2016-04-12 07:22:15    93
 9: 2022484421 2016-04-12 07:22:20    94
10: 2022484408 2016-04-12 07:22:25    93
11: 2022484421 2016-04-12 07:22:35    92
12: 2022484421 2016-04-12 07:22:40    89
13: 2022484447 2016-04-12 07:22:50    83
14: 2022484488 2016-04-12 07:22:55    61
15: 2022484411 2016-04-12 07:23:00    60
>
```

Now that we have that out of the way, we *round* the Datetime to minutes (and ensure to returns a POSIXct in a single column), and then use `data.table` to run a simple aggregation (here: `mean()`) by rounded minutes.

```
> D[, min := as.POSIXct(round(final_date_time, "mins"))][, .(avgspeed=mean(Speed)), by=min]
                   min avgspeed
                <POSc>    <num>
1: 2016-04-12 07:21:00    101.6
2: 2016-04-12 07:22:00     93.2
3: 2016-04-12 07:23:00     77.0
>
```

The code is a one-liner, but it looks a like nicer here with either a line break, or a voluntary split into two lines:

```
> D[, min := as.POSIXct(round(final_date_time, "mins"))]
> D[, .(avgspeed=mean(Speed)), by=min]
```

There are base R idioms to do the same via `ave` or `aggregate`, as there are of course `dplyr` calls.  I happen to prefer `data.table`.